# How to get yes/now if a file have an extension or not

Tags: javascript, file, file-extension, dropzone

I use the [react Dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/) to select files and I wanted to exclude files that don't have a file extension.

I select files with Dropzone and scanning them if they have a file extending or not like

I try various things like

```
return filename.split('.').pop();
```

That returns the filename if there is no file extension and if there is a file extension it returns the extension like "exe" or "png".

But how to know if there is no extension on the Dropzone selected file?

E.g. files with extensions
file.png
file.exe
file.text

E.g. files with no extensions
file
file
file

Comment: While outside the scope of your question, it's probably prudent to put it out there that a file's extension never necessarily corresponds with its *contents*, and you should be performing checks on the server-side to ensure that they do in fact match.

Comment: @esqew Dropzone do return props like Meme type 'image/jpeg' or 'application/pdf' that comes from  the browser but it's kind of not always working for some files.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the length of the splitted array, e.g.:

```js
var splitted = return filename.split('.');
return splitted.length > 1 ? splitted.pop() : null;
```

Comment: Thanks but what if the filename have two "." ? Some filenames do have a "." for other reasons than file extension

Comment: @Kid There's nothing magical about file extensions - if your file is called `somethigweird.somethingodd`, by definition, `somethingodd` is your file extension.